# How significant is the impact of the type system (static/dynamic) on the overall design of programs?

Tags: design, programming-languages, dynamic-typing, static-typing

Coming from Java, I've never used a language with dynamic typing. I'm very used to the static-typing way of thinking.

My question is, how much does the use of dynamic typing as opposed to static typing influence the overall design of programs written using languages with that kind of typing?

**Does the kind of typing (static/dynamic) influence the design of programs significantly?** Working with a dynamically-typed language, would you structure your application differently than working with a statically-typed language? **Or is it merely a language characteristic that affects mainly local implementation details, but doesn't affect overall designs?**

Comment: Design of programs as in how the various high-level components fit together, or design of programs as in how the various high-level components that make up the program look?

Comment: @delnan Actually I'm referring to both. But mainly the second one, regarding the implementation of high level components.

Comment: It's a bit hard to judge, because statically typed languages have traditionally had poor or no support for first-class functions (e.g. Java only just now got support for lambda expressions), sum types/tagged unions (you kinda get this for free in dynamic languages), tuples and records (none of C++, Java, or C# have them as far as I know) or syntax sugars like list comprehensions. These sorts of things do matter; you didn't see much functional programming being done in Java before, but passing functions around is no big deal in Python. But none of this is inherent to either type system.

Comment: @Doval What about the numerous functional languages with quite powerful type systems (Haskell for example has everything you mention since 1990)? Of course the functional paradigm has a huge impact independently of the typing discipline, but there are dynamic predominantly-functional languages too, so this would make a nice case study. There might be a shortage of data points regarding large, enterprisey projects though, as FP is historically... less popular.

Comment: MLs like OCaml and Haskell are almost obnoxiously strongly statically typed and have first class functions out of the box. Ada is statically typed as well and has most of the other features.

Comment: @Doval: Your C# knowledge seems to be a bit dated.  C# has had first-class functions (delegates) since the beginning. [Tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) are available, as are list comprehensions (Linq).  The rest of the things you mentioned can almost certainly be simulated.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'll grant you that, but C#'s tuples are just parameterized/generic records. This makes a difference in practice since method argument lists are not tuples, so you can't compose methods as easily. You also can't create tuples as easily, and have to unpack their contents into local variables if you want them to have meaningful names in the context of some piece of code. In a language with pattern matching that's not an issue. Also, there was a point in time where C# didn't have generics, so Tuple wouldn't have worked then...

Comment: @RobertHarvey ...anonymous types are kinda like records, but you can't return them from methods, which really hurts their practicality. Granted, linq is effectively list comprehensions, but I never said C# doesn't have them.

Comment: @Doval: Some of what you're describing (like dynamic binding of records) can probably be done with `dynamic`.  In fact, it's been done before; Rob Conery wrote a whole ORM based on `dynamic` that is only about 600 lines of code.

Comment: @delnan That's all true; when I said "traditionally" I had the Algol/C/curly-brace family of languages in mind. I only get so much space in the comments section! They're certainly worth bringing up, and reinforce my point that the availability or lack thereof of language features has a big impact in how programs are written. You're far more likely to see new functions being defined through composition (i.e. `foo = bar . baz`) in those languages, far more likely to see recursion, etc.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sure, but you lose the type safety then, don't you?

Comment: @Doval: It's still type-safe, but type checking is deferred to runtime.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ergh, that's what I meant. Like WorldEngineer mentions, in ML-like languages records are still *statically* typed, you get them out of the box, and they're idiomatic since functions only ever have 1 argument in those languages.

Comment: @Doval The Algol and C languages are several decades old. They are traditional in the sense of carrying inertia and having influenced the development of the field, but not traditional in the sense of being deeply rooted and without rival, for the purposes of this question. My point is that there should be enough code using (and general experience with) the rich static type systems you mention to make an answer feasible.

Comment: @delnan I agree. That inertia is very powerful though. What I'm trying to get at is that people that learned to program in a curly brace language are far less likely to think in terms of higher-order functions, or monads, or recursion, or persistent data structures. And even if they know about these things, depending on the language, some of them may be impractical. There's still no easy way to write an algebraic data type in Java or C#, you have to jump through quite a few hoops with inheritance and lambdas. In ML you can define a new type in one line, in Java I need like 40 for a value type.

Comment: @delnan Another example is that the JVM doesn't really have the bytecodes needed for tail calls, which makes deep recursion a real issue. So unless you're traversing a tree, you'd be told to write a for loop or while loop. Scala has to jump through quite a few hoops to implement simple tail call elimination, and it doesn't cover the more complicated cases if I remember right. In SML/Haskell/Ocaml you get that for free, guaranteed.